# Bootstrap Table Filter by Multiple Columns

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using Bootstrap Table by wenzhixin. I need to filter by several columns. For example, I need to filter Countries and then Cities.

I have two select fields for each field in the table (Select Country and Select City).

The way I am doing it right now is I apply *filterBy* method on change of select option:

```
    $('#countries-list').on('change', function (evt) {
        var selectedCountry = $('#countries-list').select2('val');
        if (selectedCountry == "all") {
            $tableFilter.bootstrapTable('filterBy');
        } else {
            $tableFilter.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {country: selectedCountry});                
        }
    });

    $('#cities-list').on('change', function (evt) {
        var selectedCity = $('#cities-list').select2('val');
        if (selectedCity == "all") {
            $tableFilter.bootstrapTable('filterBy');
        } else {
            $tableFilter.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {city: selectedCity});              
        }
    });
```

The problem is that they overwrite each other. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to apply second filter only to the results of the first one, not to the entire dataset.

Thank you!

Comment: I created the table using angular ng-repeat and custom filters. All filters work now, but still have some other issues... So, if you come up with a solution it's not too late to share ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you use the bootstrap-table extension **Filter-Control**.

- [Example](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/develop/extensions/filter-control.html)
- [Github project](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/filter-control)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I have actually tried that, nice extension! The problem is that my stakeholders want the input fields for filters to look some particular way, separately from the table. I could not figure out how to make this work with input fields that are located just on the page, not in the header of the table. Hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly old question but I just struggled with the same thing today and just figured out a solution.

Set needed variables:

```
var $table = $('#table-id')
var FilterOptions = {}
```

Create a function to check if a object is empty:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
        for(var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Create a function that will filter the table with the help of our isEmpty() function:

```
function FilterTable(){
        if(isEmpty(FilterOptions)){
            $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {})
        } else {
            $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', FilterOptions)
        }
    }
```

Then for each of our select fields we will create a function that adds/change a property to our FilterOptions object depending on what is selected or deletes the property if the default option is selected ("all" in this example). At the end we filter our table with our FilterTable() function.

```
$('#Selector_column1_filter').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != "all") {
            FilterOptions.column1 = $(this).val();
        } else {
            delete FilterOptions.column1;
        }
        FilterTable();
    })
```